# Bing Ads API: How to get total spent amount for given account using CURL/SOAP

Tags: php, curl, soap, bing-api

**As I want how much amount have spent on that account for ads by using the bing ads api**. I need to integrate that code in PHP.

My question is to get the total spent on given account by using the **bing ads api**

If any one has any idea, please share with me. I have already search a lot but not get the what I have expected.